# При прокрутке растягиваются строки в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Почему при прокрутке растягиваются строки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**item_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pic1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:padding="6dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Filim Name"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/album_title"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Album> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Activity activity;

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Album> arrayList, Context context) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.Title.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        String path = Config.img_path + arrayList.get(position).getId();
        Glide.with(activity).load(path).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.notfound).into(holder.Thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView Thumbnail;
        TextView Title;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.album_title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: нужна разметка айтема и код адаптера не помешает тоже. Разметка активити тут вообще лишняя

Comment: @ pavlofff Добавил

Comment: высота корневого контейнера для айтемов списка должна быть wrap_content (по высоте содержимого), а не match_parent (по высоте родительского элемента, который в данном случае размер всего виджета RecyclerView)

Comment: @pavlofff Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скопируйте этот:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pic1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:padding="6dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Filim Name"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/album_title"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Это из за того, что у вас item растягиваются по высоте родителя. Также советую вам убрать `LinearLayout`, и заменить на `CardView`.

Примерно так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/pic1"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Filim Name"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/album_title"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Надеюсь вам помог мой ответ, если будут вопросы - задавайте.

Comment: Добавил свой вариант, может вам понравится и подойдет под вашу задачу.

Comment: ширина корневого контейнера  айтема (здесь CardView) указывается match_parent обычно (на всю ширину списка то есть)

Comment: @pavloff В зависимости от того какой тип Layout используется, разве нет? Я в GridLayout использую wrap_content, иначе он будет по ширине родителя, а мне нужно чтоб он был по ширине вложенной ViewGroup

Comment: Вопрос решен. Но хотелось бы еще, чтобы не создавать новую тему, узнать, как в данном случае при клике на картинку показывать ее на весь экран и при этом листать вправо-влево всю данную галерею?

Comment: @Сергей, если листать вправо-влево, то ViewPager, но нужно посмотреть, можно ли задать Layout(у)  Horizontal(ое) положение, я бы смотрел в эту сторону. А по поводу зума я использую библиотечку https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout. Надеюсь вам помог мой ответ.